# Add logs and sysout

Tags: java, logging

I have been asked to add logs and sysout before the class declaration.What logs should I use and how to add Sysout??What is the significance of adding these in this program?Also I am asked to create constant field for Staff Id and first name.Does that mean I should create constant variables that will store staff id and first name??

```
public class Read {

  public static void main(String argv[]) {

    try {

    File fXmlFile = new File("/Users/mkyong/staff.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);


    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("staff");

    System.out.println("----------------------------");

    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

        System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

            System.out.println("Staff id : " + eElement.getAttribute("id"));
            System.out.println("First Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("firstname").item(0).getTextContent());
            System.out.println("Last Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("lastname").item(0).getTextContent());
            System.out.println("Nick Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("nickname").item(0).getTextContent());
            System.out.println("Salary : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("salary").item(0).getTextContent());

        }
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that by *Sysout* they mean `System.out.println` and as I can see, you have already added those.

By `logs` I assume it is meant using a logging implementation. An example of using `java.utils.logging.Logger` is this:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Main {

  private static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getSimpleName());

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LOGGER.info("Logging an INFO-level message");
  }
}
```

As you can see, some of a `Logger`'s purpose is to output text that is using for diagnosing (debugging, monitoring). It can output the text to a console, file, database and it formats it in whatever way you want.

Using a logger vs plain `System.out.println` offers a lot more power and control.

> Also I am asked to create constant field for Staff Id and first name

You got the idea here. It means creating constants for `"firstname"`, `"staff"`, `"lastname"` and any other string. Then, where you need to use that string you use the constant:

Ex:

```
private static final String STAFF = "staff";
private static final String FIRST_NAME = "firstname";
```

The advantage of doing so is that you can see all your constants in a single place and easily modify them when you need to. Imagine using `"firstname"` in 5 places. Than you realize you meant to use "first_name" instead. If you don't use constants you would have to change it in 5 places, else, just in 1 place.

Answer (score 0):

"you have been asked", When your homework is not clear you should ask your TA first.

Besides, "/Users/mkyong/staff.xml" looks very very suspicious to me. since [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/) is a very famous developper. You should not take examples from the internet and copy/paste them without understanding them.

That said, yes you should declare static final fields to be constants, such as

```
private static final String STAFF_ID = "Staff id"
private static final String FIRST_NAME = "First Name"
```

and then replace those values in your code.

As for logging and sysout, sysout just means adding

```
System.out.println("something you would like to print")
```

Logging does the same thing but using a framework and giving more information automatically, such as the time the line was printed and which class triggered the print It also gives flexibility on when to print messages.
 See this first
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_logging_framework